# How to plot kriging analysis when packages presents conflicts and the option :: doesnt work?

Tags: r, database, plot, maps, kriging

I did a plot with set packages (geoR", "oceanmap","raster"); however, it was possible to build the figure below (the current figure is a print screen because it has a higher size than permitted, sorry by this); It is important to clarify that this figure was built it had not edited by other programs. [image: figure].

The current functions of these packages build figures unmatched with all parts disordered.

This is my code

```
require(oceanmap);require(geoR);require(raster);data(cmap)
set.seed(1000)

Y <- data.frame(Lon=runif(65,-92.43,-86.29), Lat=runif(65,20.73,23.75), 
               Data=runif(65,0.5,4.1));Y

cgeo <- as.geodata(Y)
plot(cgeo)

varigr <- variog(cgeo, direction="omnidirectional")
plot(varigr, pch=19,col="red")

gnt <- likfit(cgeo,ini=c(1.5,1.5),fix.nug=FALSE,cov.model="gneiting");gnt
borders <-data.frame(
  Lon=c(-92.21361, -91.17074, -88.60174, -86.57961, -86.14720, -86.18536, -86.22351, -86.35069, -89.37753, -92.49340,-92.46796, -92.45524), 
  Lat=c(20.76919, 20.78056, 20.84879, 20.87722, 20.87722, 22.27024, 23.10037, 23.80540, 23.83383, 23.81678, 22.38964, 20.82605))


grids <- expand.grid(lon=seq(-93, -85.5, length=600), lat=seq(20.5, 24.5, length=600))

krig<-krige.conv(cgeo,loc=grids, krige=krige.control(cov.pars = gnt$cov.pars,
                                                 cov.model = "gneiting", 
                                         type.krige = "ok", nugget = gnt$nugget),borders=borders)

image(krig, borders=NULL)
contour(krig, add=TRUE, borders=NULL, col="white", cex=1)

text(Y$Lon, Y$Lat, rownames(Y), cex=0.8)
plotmap(lon=c(-92.5, -86), lat=c(20.5, 24.5), add= TRUE, 
    col.land= "forestgreen",cex.lab = 0.9, grid.res = 1.5, border="black", bwd=1, cex=0.8)

compassRose(-92, 24, rot=0, cex=0.6)
scalebar(100, xy= c(-89.2,20.89), type = "bar", divs = 4, cex = 0.8, below = "Kilómetros", adj=c(0.5, -1))

legend.krige(x.leg = c(-85.79,-85.69), y.leg =c(20.7, 24.2), col=cmap$jet, cex=1,vertical=TRUE, 
         val= krig$predict,scale.,offset.leg=0.9, family="Times New Roman")
par(fn)
```

The problems are:

1. The current figure it is impossible to plot, and there are problems with packages when they are called with ::
2. Sometimes the plot isn't built or the figure obtained is unconfigured inside the limits established with the kirging area close to the left-side and the map in director to the right.
3. The most common problem is that the kringing area disappear when plotmap function is called.
4. Stations position unmatch with the kriging area.

I appreciate the help with this question.

Comment: I edited your code so that it actually runs; Make sure you try it in a clean R session, so that you do not refer to things that are not in the script. I also simplified it a bit to help focus. I think the example still needs more work --- and the actual question clarification.

Comment: Thank you Robert, but the problems continue I going to try with other computer, maybe it is a hardware issue.

Comment: It is not a hardware issue